# Spring LdapTemplate search on multiple bases with separate filters

Tags: java, spring, spring-ldap

Having the following organizational structure in corporate Active Directory;

> - DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=com
>
>   - OU=employees
>
>     - CN=employee1
>     - CN=employee2
>   - OU=interns
>
>     - CN=intern1
>     - CN=intern2
>   - OU=x
>   - OU=y
>   - OU=z

I need to retrieve a single list of;

> employees having attribute "A" and **not** having attribute "B" 
>   and interns having attribute "B" and **not** having attribute "A".

Generating Spring LDAP's `LdapContextSource` by setting **DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=com** as base, I can't see any search API on `LdapTemplate` for setting multiple search bases having individual filters.

Here is a sample code which doesn't return any matches;

```
@Configuration
public class LdapConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LdapContextSource contextSource () {
        LdapContextSource contextSource= new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.url"));
        contextSource.setBase("DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=com");
        contextSource.setUserDn(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.user"));
        contextSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty("ldap.password"));
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LdapTemplate ldapTemplate() {
        return new LdapTemplate(contextSource());        
    }

    private List<Contact> ldapsearch(AndFilter filter) {
    OrFilter orFilter = new OrFilter();
    // EMPLOYEE FILTER
    AndFilter employeesFilter = new AndFilter();
    employeesFilter.and(filter);
    // ou=employees
    employeesFilter.and(new EqualsFilter(DirectoryConstants.OU, DirectoryConstants.EMPLOYEES));
    // A=*
    employeesFilter.and(new PresentFilter(DirectoryConstants.A));
    // (!(B=*))
    employeesFilter.and(new NotPresentFilter(DirectoryConstants.B));
    // INTERN FILTER
    AndFilter internFilter = new AndFilter();
    internFilter.and(filter);
    // ou=interns
    internFilter.and(new EqualsFilter(DirectoryConstants.OU, DirectoryConstants.INTERNS));
    // (!(A=*))
    internFilter.and(new NotPresentFilter(DirectoryConstants.A));
    // (B=*)
    internFilter.and(new PresentFilter(DirectoryConstants.B));

    orFilter.or(employeesFilter);
    orFilter.or(internFilter);

    List<Contact> contacts = null;
    try {
        contacts = ldapTemplate().search(
                "",
                orFilter.encode(),
                new AttributesMapper<Contact>() {
                    public Contact mapFromAttributes(Attributes attrs) throws NamingException {
                        return buildContact(attrs);
                    }
                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Active directory search failed. " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return contacts;
}
}
```

I believe the filters `ou=employees` and `ou=interns` above should not be part of the filter, instead they should be part of the `base` (first parameter of `ldapTemplate().search()`). However I couldn't find any API for neither setting multiple bases to `ldapTemplate().search()` nor setting individual filters per base.

Any ideas on performing this query in single step?

Comment: Although Spring LDAP's configuration is straight forward, I inserted an example code anyways as per @TobySpeight's comment.

Comment: Either you start your search higher up in the tree, at a common ancestor node, or you do it in two separate searches and join the results afterwords.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @marthursson. I already tried both ways and as obvious both increased the query time. However in my case because of the overloaded and not very well structured corporate AD structure, it is quicker to perform two separate queries. This is the logic in my application as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter item that its OU is DirectoryConstants.EMPLOYEES with the LdapQuery.base(DirectoryConstants.EMPLOYEES). The below code show that find all item that its OU is 'dev' and attribute named objectClass is 'group'.

```
LdapQuery query = LdapQueryBuilder.query()
            .base("ou=dev")
            .where("objectClass").is("group");

    return ldapTemplate.search(query, new AttributesMapper<String>() {
        @Override
        public String mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
            return (String) attributes.get("cn").get();
        }
    });
```